# The effects of H2o2 (hydrogen peroxide) with oils

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have some 35% $\ce{H2O2}$ that I've been cutting down to 3% to create a product. Cheaper than buying pre cut solution from store.

However, I've been thinking about trying to try it out with producing a new product which would induce mixing of the $\ce{H2O2}$ with pure oils and essential oils. I am not sure if the $\ce{H2O2}$ would break down the oils and render them useless in the product or not.

I select $\ce{H2O2}$ cause I want it to be able to kill germs to help kill a particular smell. But I want the oils to maintain their properties in which they keep there defined smells. So pretty much the $\ce{H2O2}$ is a catalyst to make to oils more liquidity able to spray and also helping hide original scent.

Answer (score 2):

Oils will oxidize (and burn, too). With dilute H2O2, it's not a rapid reaction (in laymans terms)... some oils (like linseed) will oxidize more rapidly than others (like mineral oil).

Essential oils are not really oils... they are more like phenolic and terpenic extracts.

Comment: And hydrogen peroxide decomposes much more rapidly when contaminated (except by phosphates). You'd wind up with partially oxidized "oils" and water.

Comment: Would yall have a suggestion of a better substance to use then? I am pretty much trying to make something that will mask normal smell and replace it with the smell of an oil:ex ( acorn, pecan etc..). To make a smell mask i mix H2o2 with baking soda. { H2o2 to kill germs, baking soda to deodorise a neutral smell} . Hence the reason i suggested using H2o2

Comment: @JonathanSzychulski How about febreze? The active masking-ingredient in febreze is hydroxy-propyl-beta-cyclodextrin (plus various scents).

Comment: yes i was just reading about what was inside febreze. Thing is i cant really have a "fragrance" smell. It is for hunting, in which i own a outdoor brand. so therefore i need to hide to human scent . (which i can already reproduce) but have been working on a way. To mask the human scent but add a natural smell from the woods. I can accomplish this by just boiling up a tea type substance outta items found in the woods but after a week- a month it breaks down. so trying to find away to make it last longer which id assume finding the right chemicals would do the trick

Comment: @JonathanSzychulski hydroxypropyl beta-cyclodextrin is the thing that would mask your scent. I can't recommend a good preservative for dirt tea (for use as a cologne). I might recommend geosmin (aka petrichor oil) as a scent.